# Maven ant task to add system path jar to WAR file

Tags: maven, ant

Running into a small problem. I have a spring-maven project. And there are some external jars I need to add into the POM which I did using . 
Now to build the WAR file we are using an Ant Maven task i.e. artifact:mvn providing the argument war:war.
Here somehow my external jars are not getting added to the WAR file i.e. WEB-INF/lib

Can some one please let me know if I am missing something. Below is my pom entry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>{test}</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/test.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `test.jar` locally using `mvn install:install-file` ([docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html)). Now you can remove the `system` scope (and the `systemPath`) and everything will work out of the box.

Comment: Trying to deal with the same issue. The problem is that this solution, while formally correct, is not always practical: in my case we build our project on many machines. Following tricky steps on every machine in addition to the basic git pull is very inconvenient.

Comment: @AlexNevidomsky: In your case, you should install a local proxy server a.k.a "repository manager" and configure all dev machines to use that. This way, you can also make sure that no one accidentally pulls in unwanted code (like projects with a GPL license). You can then use `mvn deploy` to deploy the file to the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to start using a repository manager (a.k.a "Maven proxy server") and install the needed artifacts (test.jar) into the repository manager and use it as a usual dependency instead of using `system` scope via systemPath.

Calling mvn war:war via Ant does not make sense and shows you should learn how Maven works.

Change the packaging type in your pom file to `war` and you can simply call maven via:

```
mvn clean package
```

and everything should work. But this is only gues cause you didn't show your full pom file.

Comment: Problem: how to avoid installing artifacts on every build machine and simply bring them with the project instead?